# what makes c++ atomic atomic

Tags: c++, atomic

I just know that even the code `int64_t_variable = 10` is not an atomic operation.  for example

```
int64_t i = 0;
i = 100;
```

in another thread (say T2) it may read the value which is not `0` or `100`.

1. is the above true?
2. `std::atomic<int64_t> i;  i.store(100, std::memory_order_relaxed)` is atomic.  so what magic does atomic use to make it happen based on Q1 is true?
3. I always think any operation which handles less than 64 bits is atomic (assume 64 bit cpu), looks I was wrong.  so for  `v = n`,  how I can know if it is atomic or not?  for example,  if v is `void *`, is it atomic or not?

==================================

Update:   In my question:  when T2 read the `i`,  both 0 and 100 are ok for me.  but any other result is not reasonable.  This is the point.  so I don't think cpu cache or compiler stuff can make this happen.

Comment: Everything that is not atomic is not atomic.  Even `char`.  Complex objects may need higher level inter-thread protections (condvar, mutex, locking).  Non-volatile objects may be optimized is surprising ways that thwarts using them across threads.

Comment: The "atomic" in `std::atomic` doesn't mean "will be atomic on the processor level" but "you are guaranteed that this operation is not interleaved with other operations on the same object". You can prevent interleaving with e.g. locks, hence [`std::atomic::is_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) and [`std::atomic::is_always_lockfree`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) exist to tell you whether locks are necessary for the given atomic instance or type.

Comment: @Eljay  how to understand `char` is not atomic?   we can take `c = 's' ` for example.

Comment: It's the other way around: `char` is not guaranteed to be atomic, so you can't assume that it will work correctly when shared between multiple threads. `std::atomic<char>` will work correctly, and if a plain `char` happens to meet all the requirements for atomic objects, then `atomic<char>` won't do anything extra. If plain `char` doesn't meet all the requirements, then `atomic<char>` will do whatever is necessary.

Comment: @Eljay 1) Which real world CPU does *not* provide atomic read and write instructions up to the natural word size? 2) Where is that word size less than 32 bits?

Comment: @curiousguy • the DEC Alpha CPU only provided read and write instructions for the natural word size, not for char size.

Answer (score 4):

> is the above true?

Yes.  If you do not use synchronization (`std::atmoic<>`, `std::mutex`, ...) then any change you make in one thread can not be assumed to show up in other threads.  It could even be the compiler optimizes something away because there is no way it can change in function.  For example

```
bool flag = true;

void stop_stuff() 
{ 
    flag = false; 
}

void do_stuff()
{
    while (flag)
        std::cout << "never stop";
}
```

since there is no synchronization for `flag`, the compiler is free to assume it never changes optmize away even checking flag in the loop condition.  If it does then no matter how many times you call `stop_stuff`, `do_stuff` will never end.

If you change flag to `std::atomic<bool> flag`, then the compiler can no longer make such an assumption as you are telling it that this variable can change outside the scope of the function and it needs to be checked.

Do note that not providing synchronization when you have more than one thread with shared data and at least one of those threads writes to the shared data is called a data race and per the standard is undefined behavior.  The above example is just one possible outcome of that undefined behavior.

> `std::atomic<int64_t> i;  i.store(100, std::memory_order_relaxed)` is atomic. so what magic does atomic use to make it happen based on Q1 is true?

It either uses an atomic primitive your system provides, or it uses a locking mechanism like `std::mutex` to guard the access.

> I always think any operation which handles less than 64 bits is atomic (assume 64 bit cpu), looks I was wrong. so for  v = n, how I can know if it is atomic or not? for example, if v is void *, is it atomic or not?

While this may be true on some systems, it is not true for the C++ memory model.  The only things that are atomic are `std::atomic<T>`.

Comment: To be perfectly clear: if more than one thread accesses an object and at least one of those accesses modifies the object, that's a **data race**, and the behavior is undefined. One common consequence of that is "any change you make in one thread can not be assumed to show up in other threads", but that is by no means the extent of the possible problems.

Comment: @PeteBecker Added that into the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's is not something I want.   in your case, the flag can be either true or false,  which any compiler and cpu cache & store buffer can make that.   Here I'm asking a case that is it possible to get a data which is not "true" or "false" in your example.   If you check my question,  it is not "0" and not "100".  @NathanOliver

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Reasons include "it requires multiple instructions", "memory caching can mess with it" and "the compiler may do surprising things (aka UB) if you fail to mention that the variable might be changed elsewhere".
2. The above reasons need to all be treated, and `std::atomic` gives the compiler/C++ library implementation the information to do so. The compiler won't be allowed to do any surprise optimizations, it might issue cache flushes where necessary, and the implementation may use a locking mechanism to prevent different operations on the same object from interleaving. Note that not all of these may be necessary: x86 has some atomicity guarantees built in. You can inform yourself whether a given `std::atomic` type is always lock-free on your platform with [`std::atomic::is_always_lockfree`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free), and whether a given instance is [lock-free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free) (due to e.g. aligned/unaligned access).
3. If you don't use `std::atomic`, you have no atomicity guarantees due to the above reasons. It might be atomic on the instruction-level on your CPU, but C++ is defined on an abstract machine without such guarantees. If your code relies on atomicity on the abstract machine but fails to specify this, the compiler might make invalid optimizations and produce UB.

Comment: "memory caching can mess with it" But can it, in the real world?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, for example if there is 8bit memory, another thread may read partially written variable.
2. Whatever it takes to guarantee correct results, it can be nothing, built in atomic operations, locks etc.
3. void* is not atomic std::atomic < void* > is.
   Same for the char, to be atomic it needs to be explicitly stated as atomic.

Comment: What is "8 bit memory"?